# mvc4 dynamic dropdownlistfor bind selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

i am using MVC4 ,

at controller side i have 2 List:

1> **CarrierList** :- it's contain List of transportation data.

2> **TransPortationModeList** :- it's contain the id of selected transportation data & it's coming from Database.

now, on edit mode i have to, 1st thing to bind dropdownlist with "CarrierList" record.
and also select the property of this list which id(value) should be coming from "TransPortationModeList".

for that my view code is:

```
@foreach (var Data in Model.TransPortationModeList)
                {

    @Html.DropDownListFor(lm => lm.TransPortationModeList[Model.TransPortationModeList.IndexOf(Data)].TransModeId, Model.CarrierList.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.TransportationName + "-" + c.TransportationModelID, Value = c.TransportationModelID }), TransPortationModeList[Model.TransPortationModeList.IndexOf(Data)].TransModeId, new { @class = "form-control" })

}
```

Here: **TransPortationModeList[Model.TransPortationModeList.IndexOf(Data)].TransModeId**  it's provide me the ID.

now, by this code.i am not able to bind dropdownlist for Selected record.

kindly let me know. what i am missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: How is your `Data` property initialized ? Also, you shouldn't have to specify `TransModeId` after your collection of `SelectListItem` as the selected value should be provided by your first argument (`lm => lm.TransPortationModeList[Model.TransPortationModeList.IndexOf(Data)].TransModeId`)

Comment: @RédaMattar - for Data i am using foreach. let me update my question again.

Answer (score -1):

It can be less verbose with a `for` loop, as you avoid `IndexOf` usage :

```
@for(int index = 0; index < Model.TransPortationModeList.Count; index++)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(lm => lm.TransPortationModeList[index].TransModeId,
                                Model.CarrierList.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.TransportationName + "-" + c.TransportationModelID, Value = c.TransportationModelID }), 
                                new { @class = "form-control" })

}
```

First argument will contain the selected value.